# How to convert cell units (c.u.) to mole?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-signaling

If one has values in terms of cell units (c.u.) how may it be converted to $\mu$M? Should I think a "cell unit" as

$1\;c.u.= \frac{1}{\text{cell volume}}$

and

$1\;c.u.=\frac{1}{\text{cell volume}}*(\text{volume of 1 mole of in 1 atm)} \; Mole$?

an [example](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S2211124719306813-gr1.jpg) of c.u. units, belongs to this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211124719306813)

Thank you.

Comment: Where does this "cell units" thing come from (source)? I have never used such a unit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is the second posting of this question. It is also unclear.

Comment: @tyersome **Yes it is the second posting**. If you can read the last comment on the prior question which is "I will post two questions, as David suggested, and will not erase this one to be sure that you can read my comments. Please post a comment such that I can erase this question, thank you."  **I am waiting for David to read my comments, I don't want to be rude to him. I will erase my prior question.**

Comment: @Chris I edited my question, hope it is clear now.

Comment: You can delete a question you have posted if it hasn’t been answered. Then post again in a revised form.

Comment: Ok, i will, thank you.

Comment: Please read a definition of molarity. A molar solution contains 1 mole per litre. A mole is Avagadro's Number (approx 6x10^23) of molecules of a particular substance. So you can only talk about the molarity of a single substance and to calculate this you need to know its molecular mass. A cell is not a molecule, but is a structure made up of many different molecules and macromolecules. So cell units (which don't even come up in a Google search but seem to be some way of quantitating cells) can have no relation to moles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper references c.u. to their "ODE model construction & simulation" which is referenced back to a [2016 paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0166489#pone-0166489-t001) that uses the term in reference to a simulation in MATLAB.

c.u. is abbreviation for CONCENTRATION UNIT not CELL UNIT.

> Given the absence of experimental measurements of protein concentrations, we use concentration units (c.u.) as  unit to represent the relative concentrations of proteins in the model

quoting https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2006.1761

Comment: I'm having trouble finding that quote or any instance of "concentration units" / "c.u." in the referenced paper

Comment: @user338907 thanks!